# Warnings when creating a singly linked list with arrays

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, typedef

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
}node;

void print(node *head)
{
  node *tmp = head;
  while (tmp)
  {
    printf ("%d ", tmp->data);
    tmp = tmp->next;
  }
}

int main()
{
  node arr[5] = {
                  {1, &arr[1]},
                  {2, &arr[2]},
                  {3, &arr[3]},
                  {4, &arr[4]},
                  {5, NULL}
                };

  print(arr);
  return 0;
}
```

Why do i get these warnings while compiling with gcc -Wall ? (even without -Wall, gcc produces the same warnings)

```
list.c: In function ‘print’:
list.c:15:7: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
list.c: In function ‘main’:
list.c:22:18: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by     default]
list.c:22:18: warning: (near initialization for ‘arr[0].next’) [enabled by default]
list.c:23:18: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
list.c:23:18: warning: (near initialization for ‘arr[1].next’) [enabled by default]
list.c:24:18: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
list.c:24:18: warning: (near initialization for ‘arr[2].next’) [enabled by default]
list.c:25:18: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
list.c:25:18: warning: (near initialization for ‘arr[3].next’) [enabled by default]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use `struct node` inside the definition of `node` so therefore the compiler doesn't know you mean them to be the same thing. Try forward declaring the struct first:

```
struct node;
struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};
```

Answer (score 6):

What @metalhead said was correct. Another probably better way to achieve the same result is

```
typedef struct _node
{
  int data;
  struct _node *next;
} node;
```

After this definition **node** (without underscore) can simply be used as a type name like e.g. int.

**P.S.**  The **underscore** is *just a standard convention*, not a requirement. Any name could have been used in place of _node as long as you replace in both occurrences. *However, in c this is a norm and sort of a coding convention that helps the devs to quickly understand* **_node** *refers to the node type actually*.