# Dynamically allocate memory for Array of Structs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, malloc

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct myStruct {
    int myVar;
}

struct myStruct myBigList = null;

void defineMyList(struct myStruct *myArray)
{
     myStruct *myArray = malloc(10 * sizeof(myStruct));

     *myArray[0] = '42';
}

int main()
{
     defineMyList(&myBigList);
}
```

I'm writing a simple C program to accomplish this. I'm using the GNU99 Xcode 5.0.1 compiler. I've read many examples, and the compiler seems to disagree about where to use the `struct` tag. Using a `struct` reference inside the `sizeof()` command doesn't seem to recognize the `struct` at all.

Comment: n = sizeof( struct myStruct ); and struct myStruct * mBigList = NULL;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code. Make it:

```
struct myStruct *myBigList = NULL; /* Pointer, and upper-case NULL in C. */

/* Must accept pointer to pointer to change caller's variable. */
void defineMyList(struct myStruct **myArray)
{
     /* Avoid repeating the type name in sizeof. */
     *myArray = malloc(10 * sizeof **myArray);

     /* Access was wrong, must use member name inside structure. */
     (*myArray)[0].myVar = 42;
}

int main()
{
     defineMyList(&myBigList);
     return 0; /* added missing return */
}
```

Basically you must use the `struct` keyword unless you `typedef` it away, and the global variable `myBigList` had the wrong type.

Comment: +1 for asking to avoid "struct" in sizeof and use the instance name instead.

Comment: This worked great! Thank you! The ** was the key. Virtual drinks for everyone! Thanks again. All of you cleared up a lot of the confusion.

Comment: You should free myBigList inside main()

Answer (score 2):

This is because *struct name is not automatically converted into a type name*. In C (not C++) you have to explicitly typedef a type name.

Either use

```
struct myStruct instance;
```

when using the type name OR typedef it like this

```
typedef struct {
    int myVar;
} myStruct;
```

now **myStruct** can simply be used as a type name similar to int or any other type.

Note that this is only needed in C. C++ automatically typedefs each struct / class name.

A good convention when extending this to structs containing pointers to the same type is  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17085437/986760)

Answer (score 1):

```
    sizeof(struct myStruct)
```

or

```
    typedef struct myStruct myStrut;
    sizeof(myStruct)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to work for all 10 elements for that array the line:

```
myArray[0].myVar = '42';
```

should be:

```
(*myArray)[0].myVar = '42';
```

Comment: `'42'` is not a normal character constant though!

Comment: This seems like a comment on the accepted answer, not an answer to the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the following statement

```
myArray[0].myVar = '42';
```

be this?

```
(*myArray)[0].myVar = 42;
```

myvar is an integer.

Comment: This seems like a comment on the accepted answer, not an answer to the question itself.