# How to allocate a dynamic array of struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

i have a problem with the allocation of a dynamic struct array.
The struct is composed of a char* field, that is another dynamic array of char. After i allocate all arrays, windows block the program when i try to modifty a struct content. Code:

```
 typedef struct
 {
    char *cod;
 }code;

void create_cod(code *singleCode,int codeLength);
void create_codes(code *codes, int codesNumber, int codeLength);

int main()
{
  int codesNumber=4, codeLength=10;
  code *codes;
  create_codes(codes, codesNumber, codeLength);
  codes->cod = "abcd"; /*Windows block the program here*/
}

void create_cod(code *singleCode,int codeLength)
{
    singleCode->cod = (char*)malloc(codeLength*sizeof(char));
    return;
}

void create_codes(code *codes, int codesNumber, int codeLength)
{
    codes= (code*)malloc(codesNumber*sizeof(code));
    int i=0;
    while(i<codesNumber)
    {
        create_cod(codes+i,codeLength);
        i++;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19948733/5738730

Comment: `create_codes(code *codes, int codesNumber, int codeLength)` does not return the pointer `codes`nor affects the calling code's `codes` from `main()`.  Many dupes on this one.

Comment: Can i solve the problem with return codes; ?

Comment: Consider these 2 lines: `code *codes;
  create_codes(codes, codesNumber, codeLength);`  What value does `codes` have when it is given to `create_codes()`?

Comment: Its value is an address memory

Comment: What's a `codice` (in function `create_codes()`)?  and `numeroCodici`?

Comment: C uses pass-by-value, so passing in a pointer results the pointer value being passed to the function. Altering the pointer value within the function does not affect the value in the pointer variable when the function returns. This is the same as the function not being able to alter the value of an int variable that has been passed in.

Comment: John, i fixed the code in the question.
@jxh how can i solve the problem? please

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2229498/315052

Comment: Okay, i solved returning the pointer.