# initializer element is not constant

Tags: c

I have read other answers on this topic, but they didn't help me.
I declared a global stuck:

```
    typedef stuck {
    ....
    } a;
```

and right after i initialized a dynamic array of this struct:

```
    a * severalA= (a*)malloc (sizeof (a)*3);
```

after compiling i get error : "**initialize element is not constant"** on the malloc type (bold).
any idea what am i missing here?
i tried to add const before the initialization with no success.

Comment: You should never cast the result of malloc. And avoid posting pseudo-code too.

Comment: Looks like you're _stuck_ with that issue, aren't you? :D

Comment: Write inside the function

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically allocate memory for Array of Structs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948733/dynamically-allocate-memory-for-array-of-structs)

Comment: Most likely this is because you are trying to execute code outside functions, which isn't allowed when programming. Impossible to tell with the code given though.

Answer (score 3):

In C language objects with static storage duration have to be initialized with constant expressions or with aggregate initializers containing constant expressions.

My guess is that you are trying to define several `A` as a global variable - Is that true?

In that case, `malloc()` is not a a constant expression and cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled struct

You need to change stuck to struct